# IE10+ issue - website scrolls down the page on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://www.leadercastlondon.ca/

On this site, I load leadercast.js, which seems to work fine to add responsive iFrames for both Vimeo and Google Maps.

However, on IE10+, when the page loads up, the website auto-scrolls to the white section 2/3rds down the page.

This does not happen on Firefox, Chrome or IE9.

What could possibly be causing this? I have tried cutting out bits and pieces of JS with no real luck or leads at all, aside from removing leadercast.js altogether, which does stop the autoscrolling from happening.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, it didn't happen for me on IE11. (Sharp looking design, by the way!)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for taking a look Nate and I will pass on the kind words to the designer :)